# Document AI Custom Splitter Processor labels disappeared after evaluation

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I created a Custom Splitter Processor using Google Document AI, labeled and trained it.
In the 'evaluate & test' part, after clicking 'run new evaluation', I got F1 score of 0, and no labels can be seen on the left side.

I tried to train another version, and got the same results.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots or a more detailed description of what occured?